# Multiple RemoteObjects - Best Practices

Tags: performance, apache-flex, remoteobject

I have an application with about 20 models and controllers and am not using any particular framework. What is the best practice for using multiple remote objects in Flex performance-wise?

**1) Method 1 - One per Component** - Each component instantiates a RemoteObject for itself

**2) Method 2 - Multiple in Application Root** - Each controller is handled by a RemoteObject in the root

**3) Method 3 - One in Application Root** - Combine all controllers into one class and handle them with one RemoteObject

I'm guessing 3 will have the best performance but will be too messy to maintain and 1 would be the cleanest but would take a performance hit. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice would be "none of the above."  Your Views should dispatch events that a controller or Command component would use to call your service(s) and then update your model on return of the data.  Your Views would be bound to the data, and then the Views would automatically be updated with the new data.

My preference is to have one service Class per different piece or type of data I am retrieving--this makes it easier to build mock services that can be swapped for real services as needed depending on what you're doing (for instance if you have a complicated server setup, a developer who is working on skinning would use the mocks).  But really, how you do that is a matter of personal preference.

So, where do your services live, so that a controller or command can reach them?  If you use a Dependency Injection framework such as Robotlegs or Swiz, it will have a separate object that handles instantiating, storing, and and returning instances of model and service objects (in the case of Robotlegs, it also will create your Command objects for you and can create view management objects called Mediators).  If you don't use one of these frameworks, you'll need to "roll your own," which can be a bit difficult if you're not architecturally minded.

One thing people who don't know how to roll their own (such as the people who wrote the older versions of Cairngorm) tend to fall back on is Singletons.  These are not considered good practice in this day and age, especially if you are at all interested in unit testing your work. http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on how much data you have, how many times it gets refreshed from the server, and of you have to support update as well as query.

Number 3 (and 2) are basically a singletons - which tends to work best for large applications and large datasets.  Yes, it would be complex to maintain yourself, but that's why people tend to use frameworks (puremvc, cairgorm, etc). much of the complexity is handled for you.  Caching data within the frameworks also enhances performance and response time.

The problem with 1 is if you have to coordinate data updates per component, you basically need to write a stateless UI, always retrieving the data from the server on each component visibility.

edit:  I'm using cairgorm - have ~ 30 domain models (200 or so remote calls) and also use view models.  some of my models (remote object) have 10's of thousands of object instances (records), I keep a cache with/write back.  All of the complexity is encapsulated in the controller/commands.  Performance is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of pure performance, all three of those should perform roughly the same. You'll of course use slightly more memory by having more instances of RemoteObject and there are a couple of extra bytes that get sent along with the first request that you've made with a given RemoteObject instance to your server (part of the AMF protocol). However, the effect of these things is negligible. As such, Amy is right that you should make a choice based on ease of maintainability and not performance.